# Ruby - How can I get a method name within itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to get a method name from itself:

```
def funky_method
  self.inspect
end
```

It returns "main".

How can I return "funky_method" instead?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the code:

For versions >= 1.9:

```
def funky_method

    return __callee__

end
```

For versions < 1.9:

```
def funky_method

    return __method__

end
```

Comment: Only `__method__` will work in 1.8, `__callee__` comes with 1.9

Comment: So, you're saying that `__method__` doesn't work for Ruby Version >= 1.9? According to Chetan Patil's answer, they produce different values, the caller versus the method name you're in.

Answer (score 15):

`__callee__` returns the "called name" of the current method whereas `__method__` returns the "name at the definition" of the current method.

As a consequence, `__method__` doesn't return the expected result when used with alias_method.

```
class Foo
  def foo
     puts "__method__: #{__method__.to_s}   __callee__:#{__callee__.to_s} "
  end

  alias_method :baz, :foo
end

Foo.new.foo  # __method__: foo   __callee__:foo
Foo.new.baz  # __method__: foo   __callee__:baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
def foo
  puts __method__
end
```